# Circularimage library display square image

Tags: android, xml, imageview

> I'm Using circulcar image view libary available on github. I also add it to build.gradle and sync it. but i am still not getting circular image. if I add SRC insted of background, still not getting result. where i am wrong?

```
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_screen"
    app:civ_border_width="10dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

remove this line : android:background="@drawable/splash_screen"
and Add this line :   android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"

Comment: This is not working, I already mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the background line. It will show the circular image.

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"
   android:layout_height="200dp"
   app:civ_border_width="10dp"
   app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

Image was displayed to the background that's why it was showing the square.

Comment: @CodeScan can you please show your complete layout?

Comment: thanks for concern, but I already solved this problem.